# What is the meaning of macro in front of class definition in c++

Tags: c++, class, syntax

What is the syntax in C++ that allows the following construction, where a word appears in between "class" and "class_name"?

```
namespace octave
{
  // Command line arguments.  See also options-usage.h.

  class OCTINTERP_API cmdline_options
  {
  public:
...
```

Note, I am not asking the meaning of the macro. I am not asking what it does. I am not asking if it is empty. I am asking about the syntax of class definition.

Several sources explain the syntax, but without the word in the middle, for example:

```
class class_name {
  access_specifier_1:
    member1;
  access_specifier_2:
    member2;
  ...
} object_names;
```

Note also that the following questions asked about the syntax and the answers were about something else:
[macro in front of class definition in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144971/macro-in-front-of-class-definition-in-c) and 
[C++ Class definition syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524420/c-class-definition-syntax)

Comment: Classes can have [attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not standard C++ (unless the macro evaluates to whitespace, or you're using *attributes*) but it's required by some compilers when targeting certain platforms.

A common occurrence is when building a dynamic linked library (dll) for Windows. `OCTINTERP_API` is likely set to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll, and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll.

(See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes)